# excel cannot open the file xxx.xlsx' because the file format is not valid error

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

I have difficulty open opening word and excel files suddenly. Only particular office file give me the problem. These files were previously scanned by combo fix and I believe they were damaged. The error response that I from office is

> Excel cannot open the file xxx.xlsx because the file format is not
>   valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file
>   extension matches the format of the file.

This is for excel and a similar kind of error response comes for word.

The file looks fine. I mean the size vise...

Please help me with this problem. I really appreciate your help and time....

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution but a possible work around to see/salvage the contents of your file.
If you have a Google Account

- Go to Google Docs (https://docs.google.com)
- Log  in with your credentials
- Upload the troublesome files (xlsx, docx etc)

If you are lucky Google may be able to salvage their contents.

Once uploaded, you can always download the file from Google in a variety of formats